# Google Analytics with Google Tag Manager - Turn Page Path Level 1 to Site Search Category query

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

With a site I manage, site search and site search category queries aren't present, but I was hoping to manipulate the page path URIs to form GA-readable URIs in Google Tag Manager.

Example #1

```
/search-all/search_one
```

Where 'search-all' is the site search category and 'search_one' is the site search keyword. Output required would be:

```
/site-search?search_cat=all&search_term=search_one
```

Example #2

```
/search-category1/search_two
```

Where 'search-category1' is the site site category and 'search_two' is the site search keyword. Output required would be:

```
/site-search?search_cat=category1&search_term=search_two
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

### Universal Analytics Admin

Create two custom dimensions:

- Dimension1: Search Category; Scope HIT
- Dimension2: Search Term; Scope HIT

### Your Website

Add these search informations in dataLayer:

```
dataLayer.push({
    'searchCat':'Search',
    'searchKey':'Category one'
});
```

### Google Tag Manager

Extend your current Tag for Universal Analytics type Pageview. Goto More Settings -> Custom Dimensions and set:

- index 1 and assign macro type dataLayer searchCat
- index 2 macro type dataLayer searchKey

### OR you can track it as an event.

```
dataLayer.push({
    'eventCategory':'Search',
    'eventAction':'Category one',
    'eventLabel': 'Keyword',
    'event':'fire'
});
```

Comment: This will work if you view using Events, but you won't be able to use the native GA site-search reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 Javascript variables to get first and second parts of URL.

To do that you can use document.location.pathname.split ('/').

Than go to Google Analytics tag - Fields to Set and set value of "page" field to /search? search_cat={{var1}}&search_query={{var2}}.

Activate this tag only on search pages.